# Error: Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to send some html form data to a node js file using express.  However as I submit the form I keep getting this error on the browser (I've tried different browsers and restarted the server every time):

[image]

Here's the code:

```js
import mysql from 'mysql2';
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';


let probes = [];
let measurements = [];
let to_country;

const app = express();
const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} ));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'probes&anchors'
});

con.connect((err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log("Connection not proper");
    }else{
        console.log("connected");
    }
});

app.post('/', async function(req,res){

    to_country = req.body.to_country;
    let sql = 'SELECT id FROM probes WHERE country=?';
    await con.promise().query(sql, [req.body.from_country], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        
        probes.push(rows.id);
        console.log('Probe id: ', rows.id);
    })
    console.log(probes);
    con.end();

    res.send("Loaded");
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World! From Node.js'));
app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fetch API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <label for="from_country">From:</label>
        <select id="from_country" name="from_country">
            <option>Country1</option>
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
        </select>

        <label for="to_country">To:</label>
        <select id="to_country" name="to_country">
            <option>Country2</option>
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Latency?">
    </form> 
    
</body>
</html>
```

Both files are in the same directory.
I've modified Apache httpd.conf uncommenting two lines and adding the following line as shown [here](https://redstapler.co/run-node-js-apache-server/):

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000
```

Can someone please help out? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There's some pretty weird stuff going on with promisifying. Have you considered giving `mysql2` a shot, which has native promise support?

Comment: @Evert Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately this won't solve my issue

Comment: well your code seems pretty broken in terms of how you handle async/await and callbacks, so consider it!

Comment: @Evert I'm new to using async/await as well as using express.. Could you please explain to me what's broken? I actually don't know how to fix it

Comment: At a glance, you have `app.post('/'` so this should be fine. This could be a silly error (like not restarting the server after you changed its source code) but otherwise this is quite hard to help with since you've provided rather a lot of code with lots of dependencies. You should provide a [mcve] (with the emphasis on the "minimal")

Comment: Alright I'll try to minimize it, thanks

Comment: can you provide detailed error message ? it might be helpful as code looks fine

Comment: Sure I've now attached the screenshot of the error but unfortunately it doesn't say anything more than I previously reported

Comment: are you rerouting the request coming to apache server to node.js server ?

Comment: I don't think so. How would I do that? Or can you reference me something that explains it please?

Comment: added my answer ... kindly confirm that it works ! and if you need any further help reach out in comment section of my answer

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are running apache server and node.js server on same port which requires some special configurations

you have to tell apache server explicitly to send (all or in some cases request coming from specific path) requests to node.js server (this technique is called reverse proxy technique)

this blog below might help you understand that
[here](https://redstapler.co/run-node-js-apache-server/)
or [here](https://medium.com/@chamiperera95/how-to-run-node-js-server-and-apache-server-together-ee225ece6a44)

**EDIT**

```
app.post('/', async function(req,res){
    to_country = req.body.to_country;
    let sql = 'SELECT id FROM probes WHERE country=?';
    await con.promise().query(sql, [req.body.from_country], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        
        probes.push(rows.id);
        console.log('Probe id: ', rows.id);
    })
    console.log(probes);
    con.end();

    res.send("Loaded");
});
```

can be simplified to ...

```
app.post('/', (req,res)=>{
    to_country = req.body.to_country;
    let sql = 'SELECT id FROM probes WHERE country=?';
    con.query(sql, [req.body.from_country], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
           probes.push(rows.id);
           console.log('Probe id: ', rows.id);
           console.log(probes);
           con.end();
           res.send("Loaded");
        }     
    })
});
```

Comment: I think it partially solved the issue. The `Not found` message doesn't appear enymore. However as I submit the form I get this new error in the  browser console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Proxy Error)`. It seems the requests are received from the node.js server but it won't fetch data from mysql database. I'm saying this because in the terminal from where I started my nodejs server I get back an empty array.